# How to enable a button on QDialog1 when QDialog2 closes

Tags: qt, qdialog, isenabled

I have a `QDialog` called `Dialog1` with two buttons `btnDialog2` and `btnDialog3`.

On clicking `btnDialog2` and `btnDialog3` I have have the following code run:

```
void Dialog1::on_btnDialog2_clicked()
{
    ui->btnDialog2->setEnabled(false);

    d2 = new AltDialog(this);
    d2->setWindowTitle("Dialog 2");
    d2->show();
}

void StockItems::on_btnDialog3_clicked()
{
    ui->btnDialog3->setEnabled(false);

    d3= new AltDialog(this);
    d3->setWindowTitle("Dialog 3");
    d3->show();
}
```

As expected, if `dialog2` or `dialog3` is opened, their respective buttons one `dialog1` will be disabled.

I want to re-enable the buttons on `dialog1` upon their respective dialogs closing.

**Note:**

The Main Dialog has the following two private variables to represent each dialog:

```
AltDialog *d2, *d3;
```

Any help on accomplishing my goal would be much appreciated!

Comment: Simple solution: use `QDialog::exec()` instead of `QDialog::show()`. Complicated solution: use the `QDialog::accepted()` and `QDialog::rejected()` signals.

Comment: Or `finished()`, or `done()`. As @VioletGiraffe pointed out don't use `QDialog::show()` since it screws up the emission of all the mentioned signals, which are triggered only when the dialog closes. Hiding is not equal to closing.

Comment: On the contrary, don't use `QDialog::exec()` since the reentrance of the event loop produces pseudo-synchronous code, wastes stack, etc. No need for it. Do use `QDialog::show()`, the signals will be emitted properly,.

Comment: `show` or `exec` I don't care, whatever lets me solve this problem.

Comment: @KubaOber: and how many times did you get stack overflow due to `exec()`? Having to `show`, on the other hand, mean having to keep the instance around, wasting memory. I recommend `exec()` as a more efficient approach that produces cleaner code that's easier to read and comprehend. Yes, be aware of the event loop implications, of course.

Comment: Lifetime of the object has nothing to do with the choice of `exec()` vs `show()`. You're completely free to have the dialog self-destruct when it's not visible anymore. The problem with "cleaner" code is that this code is only cleaner in limited circumstances. Often the dialog is a part of a larger state machine that you've just spaghetti-coded around `exec()` and it's very hard to modify it's response to exceptional circumstances. With exception of `QDrag` and native dialogs, there's no need to use `exec()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application needs to get notification from the specific dialog if it was closed.

You can create new slots in your **Main Dialog** to receive signals from the **d2** and **d3** dialogs; and connect, for example, [void QDialog::finished(int result)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#finished) signal to be caught by new created slots:

```
d2 = new AltDialog(this);
connect(d2, &QDialog::finished, this, &YourMainDialog::d2Finished);
d2->setWindowTitle("Dialog 2");

...

void YourMainDialog::d2Finished(int result)
{
  ui->btnDialog2->setEnabled(true);
}
```

P.S. You need to aware that `finished` signal "is emitted when the dialog's result code has been set, either by the user or by calling done(), accept(), or reject()."
Also it doesn't look right that you are creating new **AltDialog** object on every button press. It seems it should be moved to "initialization" methods of your **Main Dialog** along with signals connections.